# Dynamical Casimir Effect in expanding space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, space-expansion, casimir-effect

The [Dynamical Casimir Effect](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/424111/first-observation-of-the-dynamical-casimir-effect/) is the production of real photons from the vacuum in a system where one has moving mirrors. The frequency of the photons is related to the ratio of the velocity v of the mirrors and their separation r. Apparently the production rate goes like $(v/c)^2$.

Could the same phenomenon occur on a cosmological scale in expanding space?

In every region of expanding space we have Hubble's law given by v = H r.

Perhaps real photons are produced with a frequency given by the Hubble parameter H?

Thus matter is continuously produced as the Universe expands rather than it all being present at the Big Bang.

Answer (score 0):

Space is not bounded by reflecting mirrors, so I don't think this is happening.

Comment: reflecting mirrors are the energy input to the casimir effect, so that virtual photons become in effect real. I could imagine a model where the dark energy  turns virtual particles to real. quantization of gravitation is still in its infancy., speculative https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0550321315001790

Comment: The wavelength of real photons expand with the Universe  - hence the observed cosmological redshift. Maybe the wavelengths of zero-point vacuum modes also expand with space?